# Hp pavilion dv7 power button

Tags: hardware-failure, power, hp-pavilion

My power button is non responsive I am getting LED for charging. I've taken it apart before to change the dc jack and it was fine and a few months later it just powered off. I try to power back on and is goes to start up then shuts off. I just took it apart and came to find the ribbon cable connecting the power button/speakers cover is barely hanging on do I have to replace the whole thing or is there a way to replace the ribbon cable?

Answer (score 0):

Detach the battery and wash pins of it and the notebook(battery) and attach it. 
Then try to boot.