# Power button not working

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, hp-pavilion

I put a laptop apart several times and now power button isnt working.  I did start the computer by moving the ribbon (that connects power button and motherboard) left and right where it is attached to the motherboard several times. How do I fix this? Do I need to get a new ribbon or button?
Laptop: HP Pavilion dv7

[Hp pavilion dv7 power button](https://superuser.com/questions/517785/hp-pavilion-dv7-power-button/1098028#1098028) (I found a theme but is empty for years)

Comment: Now when i manage to start it, i get a white screen that blinks and shows lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have either Dis-lodged or Broken the ribbon connector.

You need to get either the connection fixed or replace the connector.

Below is what the connector looks like.

[image]

Bring it to someone who knows what they are doing or you could potentially ruin your laptop.

If you want to learn how to fix it, ask them if you can view it being fixed, but I would not recommend doing this yourself as the Ribbon cable & Connector are very easily broken.

Comment: Connectors look OK but i may have broken ribbon. Thank you i will contact a guy that should know how to fix this. How could i know for sure whats wrong? If i need anew ribbon i could just go buy it.

Comment: Without me physically seeing the laptop i don't know, it could be something completely different that is affecting the display but has a similar issue to the above mentioned. Best advice is to take it to a repair shop, they will tell you exactly what is wrong with it.